# iPhone Application with trail package (This App is Free for limited period)

Tags: iphone, ios

Developing iPhone Application with Entertainment domain and what to implement that when user download my app from app store will be free for limited period and after that if user got satisfy with the app then need to pay money for continue using. We can say that firstly user is downloading the trail app and after that user need to pay some charges for full version.
So is there any way to implement this with iPhone Application ?

Comment: Don't forget: apple does not allow "trial" or "beta" apps in the app store. You should think about a "light" version (which is what apple allows).

Comment: What everyone seems to be doing these days is "free" apps where you have to unlock functionality with in-app-purchases. Maybe having these extra features unlocked for the first few days (and then requiring a purchase) is possible, but Apple probably won't like it. No trials or beta, right?

Comment: @JonasSchnelli Yes i know but i want to make the app free for limited time after download and want to achieve this with single app there is no any kind of update for full version ?

Comment: @Keithbunts Great that you want make your app free for a limited time, but it will never make it in to the app store because Apple will not allow it since trails aren't allowed in the App store.

Comment: so the result is it's not possible with any other ways too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since there is no way to check 100% whether the user has previously installed the app. Thus when the user reinstalled the app the time trail would start again. You could save the install start time of the trail in the keychain to make it more persistent. But still clear my iPhone will make me be able to start the trail again.

You would be better of limiting the user in, for example, in the number of item you could save in the app. And add an in app purchase to unlock all the features.

Comment: Depending on the app, an uninstall would wipe all user data, though, and that might be a deterrent.

Comment: Settings saved in the keychain could persist even after removing the app. Since you can share data between app via the keychain.

Comment: I am not looking any kind of Update with the app talking about the first same app user installed. looking to achieve that the app free for first 30 days then after if user satisfy need to pay otherwise user can not user it

Comment: You can't do that on the Appstore.